# R find out mapping between vectors

Tags: r

I have two vectors of data, e.g.:

```
vec1 <- c("u", "v", "m", "s", "c","m", "m", "a", "k", "b", "g", "h", "m", "m", "j", "r")
vec2 <- c(1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 3,  3 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ,10,  3,  3, 11, 12)
```

A mapping was applied to both, e.g. in the above example, "1" in vec2 maps to "u" in vec1, "3" maps to "m" etc.

Is there a way in R to find out the mapping, only given the vectors as input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put them into a data.frame and remove the duplicated rows.

```
> tmp <- data.frame(vec1, vec2)
> unique(tmp)
   vec1 vec2
1     u    1
2     v    2
3     m    3
4     s    4
5     c    5
8     a    6
9     k    7
10    b    8
11    g    9
12    h   10
15    j   11
16    r   12
```

Comment: Sure why not.  Didn't realize unique worked that way on a data.frame.  Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

Use vec1 as the names of vec2. In that way you can use the named vector with the "[" function to access the implicit mapping:

```
> names(vec2) <- vec1
> vec2["v"]
v 
2
```

Note that only the first match will be returned. And if you wanted to remove duplicates:

```
> vec2[!duplicated(vec2)]
 u  v  m  s  c  a  k  b  g  h  j  r 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

If you want to pull out subsets, use the %in% function which builds a logical index:

```
> vec2[ names(vec2) %in% letters[10:15] ]
 m  m  m  k  m  m  j 
 3  3  3  7  3  3 11
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way to do it :

```
> tmp <- as.data.frame(table(vec1, vec2))
> tmp[tmp$Freq!=0,]
    vec1 vec2 Freq
11     u    1    1
24     v    2    1
32     m    3    5
46     s    4    1
51     c    5    1
61     a    6    1
79     k    7    1
86     b    8    1
100    g    9    1
113    h   10    1
126    j   11    1
141    r   12    1
```